BigInt with JSX
Today I discovered that these three lines are not the same:
<p>{`found ${releases.count} total records`}</p>
<p>found {releases.count} total records</p>
<p>found {releases.count.toString()} total records</p>

... where typeof releases.count is bigint. In the first and third lines, .toString() is called implicitly and explicitly, respectively. In the second line, .toString() appears to not be called, which results in the number not actually rendering. I'm using React if that matters.

Why doesn't {releases.count} (in JSX) stringify the expression?
What does {releases.count} (in JSX) actually do instead?
I've never worked with bigint before. Is there a way to render bigint without calling .toString()?

To me the third option is less offensive than the first, so I guess I'll stick with that. I was really surprised to find the second line doesn't output the number though.

The answer is how you are using that {releases.count}
as in 1 line under string template {releases.count} is number but when evaluating string template it becomes string.
for 2 line as  {releases.count} evaluate as bigint or whatever type of releases.count is.
and for third you are explicitly callilng toString . so i hope you got your answer.

It seems React recently added support for rendering BitInt in ReactFiber (which is not released yet), for now BitInt is just ignored.
